# Can't assign a path to action in form from Controller

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to assign a url to "action" form from Controller with `generateUrl`:

***RegistrationController.php***

```
$form = $this->createForm('app_user_registration', 
                                    $entity, 
                                    array('action' => $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_register', 
                                            array('type' => 'agent')),
                                            'validation_groups' => 'Registration'));
```

***routing/registration.yml***

```
fos_user_registration_register:
    pattern: /{type}
    defaults : { _controller :FOSUserBundle:Registration:register }
    requirements:
        _method: GET|POST
        type : agent|controleur|superviseur
```

***services.yml***

```
# app/config/services.yml

services:
    bissap.form.registration:
        class: BISSAP\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [ %fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: bissap_user_registration }

    app.form.registration:
        class: BISSAP\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

***RegistrationFormType.php***

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{

    private $class;

    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;

    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', 'email', array('required' => false,'validation_groups' => array('registration'), 
                        'label' => 'form.email',
                        'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
                        'attr' => array('class' => 'input__registerbox')))
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('username', null, array('required' => false, 'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
                        'label' => 'form.username',
                        'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
                        'attr' => array('class' => 'input__registerbox')))
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
        'required' => false,
        'validation_groups' => array('registration'),
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password', 'attr' => array('class' => 'input__registerbox')),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation', 'attr' => array('class' => 'input__registerbox')),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
            ))
            ->add('Enregistrer', 'submit', array(
                'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'registerbox__submit bc-btn')))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->class,
            'intention'  => 'registration',
        ));
    }

    // BC for SF < 2.7
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $this->configureOptions($resolver);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'bissap_user_registration';
    }
}
```

***RegitrationType.php***

```
<?php
// src/UserBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php

namespace BISSAP\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name','text',array('required' => false,'validation_groups' => array('Registration'), 
                        'attr' => array('class' => 'input__registerbox')));
        $builder->add('firstname','text',array('required' => false,'validation_groups' => array('Registration'), 
                        'attr' => array('class' => 'input__registerbox')));
        //$builder->setAction($this->router->generate('fos_user_registration_register', array('type' => 'agent')));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) 
    { 
        $resolver->setDefaults(array( 'data_class' => $this->class, 'intention' => 'Registration', 'validation_groups' => array('Registration'))); 
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'bissap_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
}
```

but i get this error :

```
Attempted to call method "generateUrl" on class "BISSAP\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType".
```

So where and how can iI used `generateUrl` to assign a URL to action?

Comment: Do you happen to have a stacktrace on that error? Because what I can make out of the code you provided, `$this` in your controller is actually referencing to class "BISSAP\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType"

Comment: we don't see any `generateUrl` method in the RegistrationFormType class

Comment: oh sorry, i forget to save change for RegistrationFormType. But however when i try to display method send with `$request->getMethod();` in _Registration Controller.php_, I have GET instead of POST.